# Making LAN connection facing problem

Tags: connection, lan

I am making LAN connection. After all to do I have checked all the settings of workgroup and all but if I am checking using the ping command to check they are connected or not??

Only from one system reply is coming. From the second system reply is not coming. And I'm accessing the workgruoup this message is displayed:

> \\ pc2 is not accessible.the network path not found"

What should I do?

I have used the link http://www.digitgeek.com/how-to-create-a-lan-connection-between-2-pcs/s.

Answer (score 1):

The PING command is useful for testing basic networking functionality, so focus on getting this to work first. You may find the second issue resolves itself.

If you're connecting two computers directly then ensure you're using an [ethernet cross-over cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable).

If your computers are connected indirectly, via a router or hub, check both cables by switching them around.

Check ICMP echo requests are not being blocked by your firewall(s). Disabling firewalls temporarily may help you determine if this is the case.

Comment: yse i hav used cross over wired.and disable the firewall.still the connection has been not established.

Comment: Can you 'ping localhost'?

Comment: Better yet, run `ipconfig` on the computers and post the results here (edit the question and add the info).